# Pi zero w not connecting to wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, headless

My new pi0w isn't connecting to my home wifi in a headless environment. Here's my set up:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether b8:27:eb:70:cb:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-04-20 22:10:45 EDT; 6min ago
  Process: 259 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 275 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
       └─275 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b

Apr 20 22:10:48 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: wlan0: carrier lost
Apr 20 22:10:48 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::bb9:396e:9a4a:cfba
Apr 20 22:10:48 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr 20 22:10:49 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 20 22:10:53 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: probing for an IPv4LL address
Apr 20 22:10:59 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.14.36
Apr 20 22:10:59 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Apr 20 22:10:59 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: adding default route
Apr 20 22:10:59 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: removing route to 169.254.0.0/16
Apr 20 22:11:02 bramble1 dhcpcd[275]: usb0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

My `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like:

```
country=US
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
network={
       ssid="xxxxxx"
       proto=RSN
       key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
       pairwise=CCMP TKIP
       group=CCMP TKIP
       psk="xxxxxx"
}
```

and my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

It's finding my relevant network when I run `sudo id dev wlan0 scan`:

```
BSS 30:46:9a:44:b9:38(on wlan0)
TSF: 0 usec (0d, 00:00:00)
freq: 2412
beacon interval: 100 TUs
capability: ESS Privacy ShortSlotTime (0x0411)
signal: -39.00 dBm
last seen: 0 ms ago
SSID: xxxxxxxx
Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5 11.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0
DS Parameter set: channel 1
ERP: Barker_Preamble_Mode
ERP D4.0: Barker_Preamble_Mode
RSN:     * Version: 1
     * Group cipher: CCMP
     * Pairwise ciphers: CCMP
     * Authentication suites: PSK
     * Capabilities: 16-PTKSA-RC 1-GTKSA-RC (0x000c)
Extended supported rates: 6.0 9.0 12.0 48.0
WPS:     * Version: 1.0
     * Wi-Fi Protected Setup State: 2 (Configured)
     * Selected Registrar: 0x0
     * Response Type: 3 (AP)
     * UUID: 3be17555-a17b-36d1-d6cb-d8633ca028e9
     * Manufacturer: NETGEAR, Inc.
     * Model: WNDR3400
     * Model Number: WNDR3400
     * Serial Number: 01
     * Primary Device Type: 6-0050f204-1
     * Device name: WNDR3400
     * Config methods: Label, PBC
     * RF Bands: 0x3
WMM:     * Parameter version 1
     * u-APSD
     * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
     * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
     * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
     * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your data looks different than mine (which works :)   How did you set up your WiFi - through raspi-config, or manually?

Comment: I manually set up my wpa_supplicant.conf file following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj3MPmJhAPU

Comment: What does you give `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan`? Do you find your hotspot?

Comment: @Ingo updated with relevant hotspot output

Answer (score 0):

OK, with `iw` we know wifi is working. Seems there is only a problem with associating. Try to use minimal [entries in wpa_supplicant](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). I'm not familiar with `dhcpcd`. I use `systemd-networkd` but when I use a fresh flashed [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-04-18](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and connect to wifi, there are no entries in `/etc/network/interfaces`. You may have a look at [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/79866).